# How to apply to all href attr using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How i do apply attr to all href's on my page.
For example:
I have :

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="mylink1">mytext1</a></li>
    <li><a href="mylink2">mytext2</a></li>
    <li><a href="mylink3">mytext3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:myFunc(mylink1)">mytext1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:myFunc(mylink2)">mytext2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:myFunc(mylink3)">mytext3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need do this without adding new id's, classes and etc. Use Js and jQuery. Please, help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
$("ul li a").each(function(i, a) {
    a = $(a);
    a.attr('href', 'javascript:myFunc("' + a.attr('href') + '")');
});
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/6CpTL/)

Note: this will apply this to only links within `ul` lists. To apply to all `a` tags across the entire page, use `$("a")...` instead.

Also, this method may fail if the `href` attributes contain certain characters like `"` or `\`. If this is a possibility, then this is a bit safer:

```
$("ul li a").each(function(i, a) {
    a = $(a);
    a.attr('href', 'javascript:myFunc(' + JSON.stringify(a.attr('href')) + ')');
});
```

Comment: Probably we do not need ul li in the selector because this may be just an example and other links may not be inside li.

Comment: @AbhinavRanjan That's a good point, I've included a note about that in my answer.

Comment: It is better now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var att = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr("href", "javascript:myFunc(" + att + ")");
});
```

Comment: This will add javascript:myFunc(mylink1) every where which is wrong.

Comment: That applies the same href to all links, not what the OP indicated he wants.

Comment: Thanks @chris, I have corrected.  First I tried to show a sample :)

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes so it will be passed as a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a[href^='mylink']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   myFunc($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: This should include `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the link from actually navigating.

Comment: I believe `e.preventDefault()` is meant to be the first statement executed in an event handler. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4771084/714969

Comment: It won't work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CpTL/1/), you missed to add `"` in `.attr(href)`

Answer (score 1):

this shoud do what you need:

```
$("a").each( function() {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr('href', 'javascript:myFunc("'+url+'")');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying the `href` assign the event handler in the actual Javascript:

```
$("[href]").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    myFunc(this.href);
});

function myFunc(value){
   alert(value);
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9RH/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('li a').each(function(){
$(this).attr('href',"javascript:myFunc("+$(this).attr('href')+")");
})
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vgd2f/)**

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes so it will be passed as a string literal. Your fiddle throws errors.

Comment: Try clicking on any of the links

Answer (score 0):

I think this could works:

```
$("a[href^='mylink']").each(function () {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).attr("href", 'javascript:myFunc("'+url+'")')
})
```

Comment: You need to wrap the attribute value in quotes so it will be passed as a string literal.